# Session is not working in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a session on MVC application

```
string roleName="Raj"
Session.Add("UserRole", roleName);
```

But in server i found that it throwing error as

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object(I'm unable to create session in server)

Solutions i tried:

> Administrator tools -> ASP.NET State Service ->  Started

Please help me..

Is there any settings need to set on web.config

Comment: What does the config file look like? look for `<sessionState>` section, and make sure the *mode* value is not set to **Off**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any reference to sessionState in your web.config file? If not, try this:

```
<configuration>
    ...   
    <system.webServer>
        ...
        <modules>
          <remove name="Session" />
          <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
          ...
        </modules>   
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, go to IIS.
2. Select Your Web Site
3. Select the Basic Setting in the right panel.
4. Select Connect as.
5. Select User Have permission to Site Folder